# How to dynamically add table rows when an option is selected?

Tags: angular

I want to add dynamic `<tr>` to a table using Angular 8. That `<tr>` should be added following select option value. It means when users select an option and click the button - a dynamic tr should be contained selected value from option.

.component.html

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01dscr">
   <option selected>Description</option>
   <option value="1">1. Mark Verndom</option>
   <option value="2">2. Jacob Brown</option>
   <option value="3">3. Steve Rogurs</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round waves-effect waves-light m-1" id="addnewrecord" (click)="addRow(inputGroupSelect01dscr)">Add Bet</button>
```

.component.ts

```
export class NewBettingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){
  }

   addRow(i) {
   alert(i);
 }
}
```

But I don't get expected results. I want to just mention here, I started Angular three days ago. My Angular knowledge is very poor. Sorry for any mistakes I have done with the code above. Help me to resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad, but here is starting point how to achieve what you want

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <select class="custom-select" [formControl]="betOption">
            <option selected>Description</option>
            <option [value]="option.id" *ngFor="let option of options$ | async">{{ option.value }}</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round waves-effect waves-light m-1" (click)="addRow()">Add Bet</button>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async">
                    <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ row.value }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`
})
export class NewBettingComponent implements OnInit {
    betOption = new FormControl();
    options$ = new BehaviorSubject([{ id: 1, value: 'Mark Verndom' }, { id: 2, value: 'Jacob Brown' }, { id: 3, value: 'Steve Rogurs' }]);
    selectedOptions$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    addRow() {
        if (!this.betOption.value) {
            return;
        }
        const yourSelectedObject = this.options$.value.find(el => el.id === Number(this.betOption.value));
        this.selectedOptions$.next([...this.selectedOptions$.value, ...[yourSelectedObject]]);
    }
}
```

PS. Note that you will need to import `ReactiveFormsModule`

Here is how it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cywztd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. you are the only person help me to resolve this.

Comment: @Xpathforlife because your question is broad. Sometimes people dont want to do anything and ask questions assuming that other will do their jobs.  Your case is different all you need is little help :)